# "Inheriting" path variables in Windows

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables

In Windows 7 I have added two user environment variables:

```
M2_HOME   %PROGRAMFILES%\Apache\apache-maven-3.0.2
M2        %M2_HOME%\bin
```

In my head, both of those should work, however, only the first one does for some reason. What I mean is that I in a command prompt can type

```
cd %M2_HOME%
```

Which works fine, but

```
cd %M2%
```

Which does not. What's going on here?

Comment: Reboot.​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug with nested environment variables in Windows 7 (maybe other versions too, I'm not sure) where if the name of the top level variable comes before the name of the nested variable alphabetically, it won't be expanded.

In your case, the top level variable `M2` comes before the nested variable `M2_HOME` when sorted alphabetically. If you change `M2` to something that comes after `M2_HOME` (eg, `M3`), you will see that it works as intended.

Comment: Now that's annoying... Guess that's also the reason why it doesn't work to add %M2% to the path as well. Any way to specify the order of these environment variables?

Comment: The only way to get around the problem is to do what I said and rename `M2` to something like `M3` or even something like `M2_PATH` would work -- as long as it's something that comes after `M2_HOME` when compared alphabetically. Alternatively, you could edit `M2_HOME` and manually enter the program files directory instead of using `%PROGRAMFILES%`, as the bug only seems to occur when you have nesting of more than two levels.